# Some videos stopped playing in Mythbuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, video-player, mythbuntu

I've had a Mythbuntu installation that was first installed somewhere around version 9 or so, and has been upgraded ever since. It has played pretty much every video in every format I've thrown at it.

However, since upgrading to 12.04, some video files do not play, and I can't determine why. It might be particular to .AVI files, but some .AVI files do play, so I'm not sure.

I've checked all the logs in `/var/log/mythv`, but found no errors.

What can I do to determine what the problem is and fix it?

Also note, I tried following [these intructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=766683), which claim to be a comprehensive installation of all codecs and software necessary to play any video, but it did not solve the problem.

---

***Update:*** As suggested, I ran the program `mediainfo` to compare two video files, one that works and one that doesn't, and here is the output, trimmed down to just the output that is different.

This is a video that works:

```
Overall bit rate                         : 1 289 Kbps
Bit rate                                 : 1 142 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 5 892 Kbps
Frame rate                               : 29.970 fps
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.131
Stream size                              : 740 MiB (89%)
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=5 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=umh / subme=8 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=12 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=2 / b_bias=0 / direct=3 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=50 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=22.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Bit rate                                 : 144 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 179 Kbps
Stream size                              : 92.2 MiB (11%)
```

This is a video that doesn't:

```
Overall bit rate                         : 1 555 Kbps
Bit rate                                 : 1 437 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 3 651 Kbps
Frame rate                               : 23.976 fps
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.206
Stream size                              : 221 MiB (92%)
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=5 / deblock=1:2:2 / analyse=0x3:0x133 / me=umh / subme=9 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=2 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=14 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=2 / b_bias=0 / direct=3 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=23 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=60 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=20.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Bit rate                                 : 114 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 142 Kbps
Stream size                              : 17.5 MiB (7%)
```

Comment: Can I ask why you have Mythbuntu particularly, rather than Ubuntu 12.04. The reason I ask is that if you are simply playing DVDs etc then the application VLC is very comprehensive and will play just about anything. It's in the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Comment: @SunDial: I use my Mythbuntu computer for a variety of entertainment uses, including the MythTV interface and infrared remote support, and playing videos is just one thing.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of a video you can not play?

Comment: @desgua: I'm not sure that I can because there may be copyright issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discovered the problem.

For some reason, under `Setup -> Media Settings -> Videos Settings -> File Types`, the entry for `avi` in the `Extension:` field had `Use default player` checked on.

I unchecked it, and then in the `Command:` field, I put in `Internal`. Absolutely every other file type uses "Internal", so I assumed that was normal.

Now it works. I don't know why **.AVI** files had a different setting, but however it got that way, I guess the "default" player had trouble with some codec or something that the Internal player handles fine.

Answer (score 3):

AVI is a container, not a video codec. What you need to do is figure out what video/audio codecs the video is encoded in, then install them. You can use something like mediainfo (not installed by default) to find out the codecs.

To install mediainfo, use

`apt-get install mediainfo`

then use it on the file via

`mediainfo <video file>`

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras ffmpeg mplayer mencoder
```